# Php mail function not working as intended?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Problem:  There is no output from either echo, nor is there any email sent despite the query returning results.

Code:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','USER','PASSWORD','MY-DB');

$result = mysqli_query($link, "'SELECT * FROM Current WHERE  Status = 'IE-Window-Missing' order by location desc" );
$headers = 'From: SCS@cl.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: SCS@cl.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if($result->num_rows >= 1){
$email = "d@cl.com";
$subject = "One or more devices have IE windows missing";
$message='The following devices are having issues: "';

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
$message.="{$row['Location']}\r\n";
}

$message.="has been accepted for review at redacted.";
if(mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
echo "Winning";
  //mail successfully sent
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
}
?>
```

Doing a straight SQL query of the DB yields results... what's going wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: Your SQL has an initial `'` - you're never checking that your query worked, so the problem is you're getting nothing to send. Check `mysqli_error`, or at the very least, the return value from `mysqli_query`;

Comment: I don't know, what *is* wrong? You are not describing a problem.

Comment: why it is tagged with mysql and mysqli?

Comment: @deceze : Sorry for the lack of clarity, opened with the problem in the question.   Brain is fried today.

Comment: Have you tried sending a mail WITHOUT any db code involved? e.g. `mail('me@example.com', 'test', 'itworks!)` and see if even that shows up?

Comment: Try debugging it put some echo's in there and see where the code gets up to. If neither Winning or Fail are printed then the script is stopping before that point for some reason. Have you got errors turned on? Have you checked for errors? have you checked the return values of your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "'SELECT * FROM Current WHERE  Status = 'IE-Window-Missing' order by location desc" );
```

The issue is that you're not checking the return value from mysqli_query. You're assuming it's working; and all your `echo` calls are inside the `if($result->num_rows >= 1){` check. So if your query fails, it will reach none of them.

The actual issue is:

```
mysqli_query($link, "'SELECT * 
                     ^
```

You've got an extra `'` at the start of the SELECT query. That will generate you an invalid SQL string, which means the query fails; and there are no records returned.

You should be checking the response from your query with `mysqli_error`, and responding appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

> Php mail function not working as intended?

No, it works as intended. For sure and granted. Looks like you have got wrong expectations.

Perhaps a reality-check with the docs helps?

- http://php.net/mail

Comment: How are my expectations wrong?  I was working straight out of the php manual and going off other examples?

Comment: You mean you read the page from top to bottom and visited the links given for further information?

Comment: just because your php code is "correct" doesn't mean your mail system is correct. PHP itself doesn't SEND mail. It just hands off the email to a delivery system. e.g. a local MTA on unix-ish boxes, or a remote SMTP server on Windows systems.

Comment: It's running on a box that runs a local SMTP server.  Hence my confusion.

Comment: @Damien.Bell: And what does the local SMTP server do that confuses you?